# Trouble inverting a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix in python that I am trying to invert. However, the result of multiplying the inverted matrix by the original matrix **does not** yield the identity matrix.

```
M = np.matrix(cv)
invM = np.linalg.inv(M)
M@invM
```

[image: image showing result of matrix multiplication]

I am not sure what could be the problem since this is a fairly simple operation. Has anyone else had this problem? or does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is that image showing? How big are the off diagonal values?  With floating point calculations, exact 0 values are rare.  Look at the numeric values of that `@`, not just an image.

Comment: what is `np.max(np.abs((Mi@M)-np.eye(M.shape[0])))`

Answer (score 2):

Likely, your matrix is [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), which means that the matrix is close to noninvertible.  You can check the condition number of your matrix using this:

```
np.linalg.cond(M)
```

The relative precision of double-precision floats is about 1e-16. For a condition number K, you lose about a factor K in precision. If K is above 1e+15, the matrix is noninvertible for practical purposes.

If you want to solve `A @ x = b` for `x`, it is often more accurate to use `x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)` rather than `x = np.linalg.inv(A) @ b`.

Here are a few matrices with different condition numbers and the quality of their inverse:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
n = 100

def test_inv(a):
    print(f'Condition number: {np.linalg.cond(a):.3g}')
    max_err = np.abs(a @ np.linalg.inv(a) - np.eye(n)).max()
    print(f'a @ a_inv - eye: maximum error = {max_err:.3g}')    

# identity matrix
test_inv(np.eye(n))

# random numbers
randmat = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(n, n))
test_inv(randmat)

# random numbers, but one row is almost a linear combination of
# two other rows.
badmat = randmat.copy()
badmat[1, :] = badmat[0, :] + badmat[2, :] - 1e-9
test_inv(badmat)
```

The output:

```
Condition number: 1
a @ a_inv - eye: maximum error = 0
Condition number: 626
a @ a_inv - eye: maximum error = 2.84e-14
Condition number: 1.64e+10
a @ a_inv - eye: maximum error = 1.53e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = np.matrix([[2,3],[4,5]])
n = m.I
i = m@n
print(i)

out:
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

Try this way.

Comment: demonstrate this with an array of floats that doesn't have quite as neat a solution.